# QGIS - does a tool exist to calculate the (PostGIS) polygons containing a given point?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins, spatial-analysis

This is the converse of the analysis provided by the [fTools plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_ftools.html) "Points in Polygon":

Given a single point and a list of vector layer polygons (PostGIS in my specific case), is it possible to list only those layers containing the point? I have a number of 'zones' mapped as PostGIS vector layers and need a simple tool to determine which zones any given point is in.

Question [#172237](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172237) poses the general question for a Java or Python solution and an answer to question [#27005223](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005223) over on regular Stack Overflow provides the SQL to do it for PostGIS data.

I'd guess that this is a very commonly required spatial analysis, so I thought I'd check it didn't already exist as a QGIS plugin before going down the SQL/coding route myself and potentially reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the spatial query plugin for this (and many other) query. It will work on either all the features or just the selected ones in both source and target layers.

Spatial Query is supplied in the default QGis install but may need to be enabled in your install.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for the swift response, glad I asked.